# Other method of solving question other than Laplace Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have a question that asks to solve:

$y''+ 4y = e^{-t}$ , $ y(0)=y_0$ and $y'(0) = y'_0$

I was wondering if there was any other (easier) way of solving this equation other than a Laplace Transformation.

Comment: The easiest way is Laplace, however you can always do variation of parameters or guess solutions

Comment: What would be the appropriate guess solution?

Comment: you can guess $y=Ae^t+Be^{-t}$ or with a $te^{-t}$ factor. Like I said Laplace is the easiest way to go

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ represents the differentiation operator, your equation can be written as
$$
         (D^2+4)y=e^{-t}
$$
Because $(D+1)$ annihilates $e^{-t}$, then
$$
          (D+1)(D^2+4)y=0
$$
which has general solution
$$
                 y = Ae^{-t}+B\sin(2t)+C\cos(2t).
$$
Substituting back in to the original equation gives
$$
      (D^2+4)y = A(1+4)e^{-t} = e^{-t} \implies A=\frac{1}{5}.
$$
So the general solution is
$$
            y = \frac{1}{5}e^{-t}+B\sin(2t)+C\cos(2t).
$$
All you have to do is to choose $B$ and $C$ such that $y(0)=y_0$ and $y'(0)=y_0'$.

Comment: this is nice and novel (to me) +1

Answer (score 0):

Since exponentials are their own derivatives, one postulates $$y(t)=ae^{-t}$$ (we often call this *undetermined coefficients*). So $$e^{-t}=y''+4y=5ae^{-t},$$ giving $a=1/5$. This gives a particular solution.

The solution for the homogeneous part is $c_1\cos2t+c_2\sin 2t$. So $$\tag{$*$}y=c_1\cos2t+c_2\sin 2t+\frac15\,e^{-t}.$$

---

With this particular choice of functions, [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) is also easy. Since a fundamental set of solutions for the homogeneous part is $y_1=\cos 2t$, $y_2=\sin 2t$, the Wronskian is 
$$
W=\begin{vmatrix} \cos 2t&\sin 2t\\ -2\sin 2t&2\cos 2t\end{vmatrix} =2.
$$
Variation of parameters gives
$$
u'=-\frac{y_2e^{-t}}{W}=-\frac12\,\sin 2t\,e^{-t},\ \ v'=\frac{y_1e^{-t}}W=\frac12\,\cos2t\,e^{-t}.
$$
Integration by parts then gives 
$$
u(t)=\frac1{10}\,e^{-t}(\sin 2t+2\cos 2t),\ \ \ v(t)=-\frac1{10}e^{-t}(\cos 2t-2\sin 2t)
$$
and the particular solution
$$
y_p(t)=uy_1+vy_2=\frac1{10}\,e^{-t}(2\cos^22t+2\sin^22t)=\frac15\,e^{-t}.
$$
Now one can combine it as above with the solution to the homogeneous part to get $(*)$. The initial conditions then give 
$$
y(t)=\left(y_0-\frac15\right)\cos2t+\frac12\left(y_0'+\frac15\right)\cos2t+\frac15\,e^{-t}. 
$$

Comment: The question then looks at when t approaches infinity, y(t) approaches 0 . Does this mean I have to evaluate cos(inf) and sin(inf) because if I do, I'll be in a spot of bother

Comment: The only way $y$ goes to zero at infinity is if $y_0=y_0'=0$.

Comment: That contradicts your solution. The sine and cosine terms need to have zero coefficients, which gives $y_0=\frac15$ and $y_0'=-\frac15$.

Comment: No, it contradicts what I said in the comment that was typed in a hurry; and note that the "goes to zero at infinity" requirement  is not part of the question. As you say, to go to zero at infinity one needs no sine nor consine. That is only achieved when $y_0=1/5$ and $y_0'=-1/5$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{y}''\pars{t}+ 4\,\mrm{y}\pars{t} = \expo{-t}\,,\qquad
> \mrm{y}\pars{0} = y_{0}\,,\quad\mrm{y}'\pars{0} = y_{0}'}$.

\begin{equation}
\mbox{Define}\quad
\mrm{z}\pars{t} \equiv \mrm{y}'\pars{t} + 2\ic\,\mrm{y}\pars{t}
\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{y}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 2}\,\Im\pars{\mrm{z}\pars{t}}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{z}'\pars{t} -2\ic\,\mrm{z}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\expo{-t}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{z}\pars{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{y_{0}' + 2\ic\,y_{0}}
\end{array}\right.\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Then,
\begin{align}
&\totald{\bracks{\expo{-2\ic t}\mrm{z}\pars{t}}}{t}  =
\expo{-\pars{1 + 2\ic}t}
\implies
\expo{-2\ic t}\mrm{z}\pars{t} - \mrm{z}\pars{0} = 
{\expo{-\pars{1 + 2\ic}t} - 1 \over -1 - 2\ic}
\\[5mm] \implies &
\mrm{z}\pars{t} = \mrm{z}\pars{0}\expo{2\ic t} +
{1 \over 5}\pars{-1 + 2\ic}\pars{\expo{-t} - \expo{2\ic t}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{see}\ \eqref{1}}{\implies} &\
\bbx{\mrm{y}\pars{t} = {1 \over 2}\bracks{y_{0}'\sin\pars{2t} + 2y_{0}\cos\pars{2t}} +
{1 \over 5}\,\expo{-t} + {1 \over 10}\sin\pars{2t} -
{1 \over 5}\cos\pars{2t}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=y, x_2=\dot{y}$, we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -4x_1 + e^{-t} \\
\end{align}
$$
More compactly, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
u \\
\dot{x} &= Ax + Bu
\end{align}
$$
where $u = e^{-t}$. The **characteristic equation** of $A$ is $\det(\lambda I- A)=0 \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm 2j$. We obtain a pair of corresponding eigenvectors for the preceding eigenvalues via $(\lambda_i I-A)\text{m}_i=0$, therefore,

$$
m_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 2j
\end{bmatrix}
,
m_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ -2j
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now we construct the **model matrix** $M$ from the eigenvectors to get:

$$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2j & -2j
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The transition matrix is then

$$
\begin{align}
\Phi(t) &= 
M
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2jt} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-2jt}
\end{bmatrix}
M^{-1} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{e^{2jt}+e^{-2jt}}{2} & \frac{j}{4}(-e^{2jt}+e^{-2jt}) \\
j(e^{2jt}-e^{-2jt}) & \frac{e^{2jt}+e^{-2jt}}{2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{e^{2jt}+e^{-2jt}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\frac{(e^{2jt}-e^{-2jt})}{2j} \\
-2\frac{(e^{2jt}-e^{-2jt})}{2j} & \frac{e^{2jt}+e^{-2jt}}{2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2t) & \frac{1}{2}\sin(2t) \\
-2\sin(2t) & \cos(2t)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The solution of the system is then determined via this formula

$$
x(t) = \Phi(t)x(0) + \int^{t}_{0} \Phi(t-\tau)Bu(\tau) d \tau
$$
where $x(0)$ the initial values.